# Update to angular/material v-6.4.7 giving me errors

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 project and I updated my angular/material to v-6.4.7
Now I've seen a bunch of errors and I'm guessing it has to do with my angular/cli version which is v-1.7.4

How can I use the latest version of angular/material on my angular2 project? Or can't I?

Versions - `@angular/material v-6.4.7 / @angular/cdk v-6.4.7 / @angular/cli v-1.7.4`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use @angular/maerial v-6.4.7 then make sure you have the same version of angular as well.

you can upgrade your project by following [this GuideLine](https://update.angular.io/)